# C++11 : A workaround for making unique_ptr from current instance (this)

Tags: c++, c++11, this, unique-ptr

I have a function `SomeFunc` which takes a `unique_ptr` of type `A` as it argument. I want to call `SomeFunc` from inside the class and send the current instance as the argument to the function. I use the following, and I get a segmentation fault. Why is that, and is there a workaround, other than using raw pointers here?

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A;

extern void SomeFunc(const unique_ptr<A>& Some1);

class A {
 public:
  A() {}
  void Success() { cout << "Hey\n"; }
  void Func() {
    const unique_ptr<A> Some1(this);
    SomeFunc(Some1);
  }
};

void SomeFunc(const unique_ptr<A>& Some1) { Some1->Success(); }

int main() {
  A a;
  a.Func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe relevant reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Comment: Of course you'll get a segfault -- you can't `delete` an object that's on the stack!

Comment: @MrEricSir: The seg fault does not happen when I create the unique_ptr. It happens, even after SomeFunc is called.

Comment: A function that takes a `const unique_ptr<A>&` makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @a.sam Exactly, the segfault occurs when your `unique_ptr` calls `delete` on an object that's allocated on the stack.

Comment: Guideline: Don’t use a `const unique_ptr&` as a parameter; use a pointer or reference instead: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the unique_ptr goes out of scope, it tries to call `delete this`.  But `this` was not dynamically allocated, hence the seg fault.

You could call Some1.release() immediately after SomeFunc, before the unique_ptr goes out of scope, which is a somewhat ugly hack.

If changing the interface is acceptable, a better solution is probably to just change your interface to accept a `const A&`, and call it as `SomeFunc(*this)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this - it only works well if the API is expecting a unique_ptr to a fully abstract class. Basically, you can just create a derived class that forwards to your instance... i.e. given

```
struct Abstract {
    virtual void someFun() = 0;
};
```

and

`T apiFun(unique_ptr<Abstract> ptr);`

and your class

```
struct MyImpl : public Abstract {
   virtual void someFun() { cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; }
};
```

then you could have

```
struct AbstractProxy : public Abstract {
    Abstract* other;
    AbstractProxy(Abstract* other): other(other) {}
    virtual void someFun() { other->someFun(); }
};
```

-- of course this won't actually delete your class in the end. But since you can't actually prevent your class getting created on the stack (in which case, deleting it will cause `bad things` (TM) to happen), you probably don't want to do this anyway. If you want to make sure your created instances always get deleted you should probably not expose a constructor and instead provide a free function that always creates instances of your class on the heap. Or however your unique_ptr is expecting to be able to delete your class.

In this case, it seems the API is broken. `unique_ptr`s should only be held by owners of the respective instance, and it doesn't seem like that function is trying to claim ownership of your instance.

Comment: Disclaimer: Code is supposed to demonstrate an idea. It has been a while since I actually did anything in C++ so it's possible this doesn't quite compile.